# EF Core connect from Google Cloud Run to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, entity-framework-core, google-cloud-run

I have tried these:

```
Data Source=/cloudsql/*****:asia-southeast2:*****;Initial Catalog=*****;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sqlserver;Password=MyPassword0!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

that `/cloudsql/*****:asia-southeast2:*****` is my instance connection name described in [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#c).

I tried public IP too like this:

```
Data Source=***.***.***.***;Initial Catalog=*****;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sqlserver;Password=MyPassword0!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

with IP address my SQL instance public IP, but it is not working.

I have enabled the sql instance connection from the Cloud Run:

[image]

How can I fix the connection string using EF Core?

This is the error I got:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use Cloud SQL SQL server with Cloud Run. But if you have a look to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-run), this connexion is not supported.

In reality, the connexion is supported, but Cloud Run service open a Unix socket to connect the SQL Server instance. And there is no SQL Server client compliant with Unix Socket and therefore, you can't access it.

To solve your issue, I recommend you to use the `Private IP` section of this page. You can also achieve the same configuration with the public IP (don't use a serverless VPC connector and go to your Cloud SQL instance, and authorized the network 0.0.0.0/0 to access to your instance), but, because you need to open broadly the authorized network, I don't recommend you this option, for security reason.

---

**EDIT 1**

Because of my bad english, let me explain more!!

The best way is to follow the documentation page: Connect Cloud SQL private IP to your VPC, use a serverless VPC connector with Cloud Run, and in your code you can use the private IP in your connection string to access the database.

But, you can also use the public IP, that I don't recommend (see below why), at least in its first naive use. In fact, you can use the pubic IP instead of the private IP in your code. Because you use the pubic IP, you no longer need the serverless VPC connector on your Cloud Run service (you don't use the VPC but the internet to reach the internet).

However, because you use the internet and Cloud Run is a multi-customer shared service, you don't know your source IP. On Cloud SQL, you need to allow any IP (0.0.0.0/0) in the authorized network section to access to your database, which is not a very secure configuration.

---

Alternatively, you can create a more complex configuration on Cloud Run to use securely the Cloud SQL public IP (but it becomes really complex). let me dig into it.

I said previously that Cloud Run is a shared service, and you don't manage the source IP when you initiate outgoing call (like connection to the database). It's true, but [you can control that!](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip)

- Firstly, you need (again) a serverless VPC connector on your Cloud Run. And you need to set your egress to ALL (route public and private traffic to the serverless VPC connector).
- Then, create a Cloud NAT in your VPC and select, at least, your serverless VPC connector subnet to be NATed when going to the internet
- Reserve a public IP on your Cloud NAT configuration

Now you have a public, static IP defined on your Cloud Run service. You can only grant it on your Cloud SQL authorized Network, to improve the security and don't let anybody access to your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: I improved my answer, with a way to be more secure with the public IP

Comment: Got it, your explanation is very thorough. Right now I am still on development phase. I will secure it later when it is in production. Thanks man!